# jQuery unserialize data serialized by PHP

Tags: php, jquery

How can I unserialize data in jQuery? remember data is Serialized by PHP. Below is given example.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:9:" img1.jpeg";i:1;s:9:"img2.jpeg";}
```

Comment: Don't use `serialize()`, use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @ AlexHowansky I saved this serialized data in the database. Now I want to unserialize data by using jQuery.

Comment: Unserialize it in php, then json_encode it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `unserialize` and `json_encode`

```
$unserialized = unserialize($serialized_from_db);
echo json_encode($unserialized);
```

But please note your sample provided: `s:9:" img1.jpeg"` this part is incorrect. The `s:9` means it expects string to be 9 bytes (this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147) provides a good guide on understanding output from `serialize`), however `" img1.jpeg` has a space and therefore is 10 bytes and fails: [demo failing](https://eval.in/783372). You can add a check to see if this failes to unserialize:

```
if ($unserialized === false)
```

When you fix the incorrect part to: `s:9:"img1.jpeg`, giving you:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:9:"img1.jpeg";i:1;s:9:"img2.jpeg";}
```

will now work, see [demo](https://eval.in/783378).

At the end of the day I would recommend as others have above, to store `json_encode`d values in your database rather than `serialize`d values.

I came up with a really hacky hack to potentially fix bad serialized data:

```
<?php
function hackFixUnserialized($unserialized_string) {
  $parts = explode(';', $unserialized_string);
  foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    $kv = explode(':', $part);

    if ($kv[0] == 's') {
      $str_without_quotes = str_replace('"', '', $kv[2]);
      if ($kv[1] != strlen($str_without_quotes)) {
        $kv[1] = strlen($str_without_quotes);
      }
    }

    $part = implode(':', $kv);
  }

  return implode(';', $parts);
}

$unserialized_from_db = <<<EOT
a:2:{i:0;s:9:" img1.jpeg";i:1;s:9:"img2.jpeg";}
EOT;

$unserialized = unserialize($unserialized_from_db);
if ($unserialized === false) {
  $hack_fix = hackFixUnserialized($unserialized_from_db);
  printf('bad unserialized, fixed to: %s%s', $hack_fix, PHP_EOL);
  $unserialized = unserialize($hack_fix);

}

echo json_encode($unserialized);
```

Demo of it here: https://eval.in/783408

Hope this helps

Comment: I added a hack to try and fix your bad serialized data.